# PHP array from mysql data - x-editable bootstrap

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I'm using x-editable for bootstrap, which is awsome for me.

With that, to return a menu for selection one needs to return an array as such to make it work:

```
$arr = array(
  array('value' => 'Male', 'text' => 'Male'),
  array('value' => 'Female', 'text' => 'Female'),
);
```

It's fine if you have to write it, but now I need to make this array from database output.

So for instance if I run a "while($row" loop, how is the output going to be an array like that. This is what I'm trying, but oviously failing at cause this is not working:

```
    $query = 'SELECT id,app_name FROM apps';
    $result = mysql_query($query) or bomb($s,509,addslashes($query),addslashes(mysql_error()));
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $arr .= Array(
                Array('value' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['app_name']),
            );
        }
    }
```

It's probably a silly question, so thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays can't be concatenated like strings.
Try something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $arr[]=Array('value' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['app_name']);
}
```